# Preventing navigationview Back Button

Tags: sencha-touch-2, back-button, navigationbar

Is there any way to prevent the default back button behavior in the navigation bar of a navigationview?

I'm trying to use Sencha Touch 2 history and linking abilities with routers, but that requires me to essentially intercept all button taps so that I can update the url.

The back button in a navigation bar creates all kinds of nightmares as far as thats concerned, and I can supply code if someone thinks they have an alternate solution, but preventing the default back button behavior seems best (so as to play nice with browser back button)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle back button you can use [**`back event`**](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-back) of `navigation view` which fired when the back button of the navigation view was tapped.. Refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761503/hiding-a-button-on-pushed-view-and-showing-it-when-back-to-list-view/12766396#12766396) on how to do it.

If you want to completely hide the back button just simply use:

```
Ext.select('.x-button-back').hide();
```

Comment: I am listening to the back event, primarily to change the URL. Then I intercept the router to prevent it from going back twice (changing the url fires the router, so you would go back twice).

Comment: The way the interception works is by comparing the url hash to the xtype of the expected view. If they match then we skip the push() because the back button does that on its own.

The problem is if you use the browser back button, the url gets changed, and if it matches the previous view, it skips the push because we've assumed the sencha back button is handling the push, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this Ext.getCmp('navigationview's id').getNavigatorBar().hide()